# Unable to delete dependency from package-lock.json and node_modules folder

Tags: npm, package, node-modules, npm-install, package-lock.json

I'm working with a particular dependency which has 2 versions, the community version and the enterprise version. They have both been installed mistakenly.

Here is what part of the dependencies section in the package.json looks like and I want to uninstall (eventually) everything but the first one. However when trying to uninstall ag-charts-community it doesn't work.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^23.2.1",
    "ag-charts-community": "^2.0.0",
    "ag-charts-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^23.2.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.2.1",
    "ag-grid-vue": "^23.2.1",
},
```

When I try to run

```
npm uninstall --save ag-grid-community
```

It deletes it from package.json, however it persists in node_modules folder and in package-lock.json. How can I delete all instances of ag-grid-community in those aforementioned areas?

Comment: 1) What happens if you delete the package-lock and then run npm i? 2) What does npm ls ag-grid-community show?